# Npgsql support for getting jsonb field as stream

Tags: postgresql, stream, npgsql, jsonb

I am trying to do the following on a jsonb field:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        using (var results = reader.GetStream(0))
        {
            results.CopyTo(stream);
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

and getting an exception telling me that GetStream is not supported for this field.
Am I missing something here or is it Npgsql that simply doesn't support streaming jsonb fields (yet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already handled in the next version of Npgsql, 3.1. Unfortunately that version is still in alpha, hopefully I'll be able to release a beta in around two months.

In the meantime you can work around this by reading the jsonb as a string, and if needed, wrapping a TextReader around it (may not be as efficient but will work).

Comment: And I suppose that for the time being I could also use NpgsqlCopyOut if I wish to work with streams, right?

Comment: I think you're confusing different types of streaming... If all you want to do is read a jsonb column, calling GetString() should be enough (unless you're in some sort of performance-sensitive situation). NpgsqlCopyOut doesn't exist anymore (removed in 3.0), and COPY is used mainly for bulk import/export.

Comment: I'm trying to write a potentially long array of json objects into an http response stream. Would GetString be sufficient or should I use COPY then?

Comment: COPY is only useful for extracting an entire table or some columns of an entire table - you can't use it to extract from only some rows (no WHERE clause). I'm guessing this makes it unsuitable for your needs. GetString should probably be sufficient for you, although it's true that for large json objects using CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess with GetTextReader would be more efficient. This will be supported in Npgsql 3.1, for now you're stuck with GetString.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for all that info! Will wait for 3.1 then :)